# mapping values are not allowed in this context, AWS EKS Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-eks

```
mkdir ${HOME}/environment/grafana

cat << EoF > ${HOME}/environment/grafana/grafana.yaml
datasources:
  datasources.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: Prometheus
      type: prometheus
      url: http://prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local
      access: proxy
      isDefault: true
EoF
```

**I get this error when I try deploy grafana to eks cluster**

Comment: I have fixed the problem, Thanks

Comment: you can post your solution below as an answer to help later other people with same problem